# PowerShell - How to add Microsoft System Center Service Manager Console MODULE

Tags: powershell, scripting

How do I add Microsoft System Center Service Manager Console 2010 MODULE. I've searched online  but only seen tutorials for 2012 modules, is there a way to powershell script for service manager 2010 ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft PowerShell to register module